# How to know exactly the state of the emulator: not working, loaded, device

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, teamcity

I have a problem and I do not know how to solve it.

How to know exactly the state of the emulator: not working, loaded, device

I'm creating a build of the application on the server using TeamCity.
It describes the steps of the assembly build.

The first step is launching the emulator with the bash script:

Step 1: Emulator start
Runner type: Command Line (Simple command execution)
  Custom script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEVICES=`adb devices`
echo $DEVICES
if [[ $DEVICES == *emulator*device* ]]
then
    echo "Emulator has already been running"
else
    if [[ $DEVICES == *emulator* ]]
    then
        adb emu kill
        echo "All previous emulator were killed"
    fi
    echo "Launching new emulator..."
    emulator @Emul -no-window &
    adb wait-for-device
    sleep 60 #android os should start completely
    echo "Emulator launched"
    adb devices
fi
```

The problem is that the emulator upon hanging. 
The script hangs on the statement: “adb wait-for-device”
And does not continue its execution.
And the build process does not continue. And then everything builds in TeamCity crash.
Have to manually connect via VNC and restart emulator.

Can you tell as well:

- or to receive information from the emulator on his condition;
  (more than the right decision “adb wait-for-device ” )
- or how to catch the time delay signal processing response and restart the script is executed within the TeamCity

Thank you for your attention to the issue

Answer (score -1):

It show only two step of Emulater.
1.Online
2.offline

to know stage of Emulator... Type following command.
C:\path to sdks\adb devices
It will show whether your emulator is active or not and show number of active emulator.